# Combobox downkey press wait for selection C# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

In my Application I have a `Combobox comboBox1` which subscribed for event `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` and `comboBox1_KeyDown`. `comboBox1` has 10 items and when the user uses down-key to navigate to 8th Item I want that the `SelectedIndexChanged` event is raised only for 8th item, not for all from 1 to 7th item.

what I am trying to achieve here is to wait for user's selection while he is trying to select the particular value using down or up key

Answer (score 0):

The `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` event will be fired every time the index changes! What you could do is to execute a certain part of code that you want according to the `SelectedIndex`. Only do this if it is the 8-th item. But you cannot stop the event from being fired when it is registered and the index changes.

The `comboBox1_KeyDown` event actually is fired when any button is pressed **down**, not only the down key. What you also could do is: don't register the `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` event, but write your own method. Then check in the `comboBox1_KeyDown` event whether the down button was pressed and whether the 8-th item is now selected and then execute your method.

```
private void comboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.KeyCode == Keys.Up|| e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) && comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 7)
    {
        // do something fancy
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I would suggest to let the user just press `Enter` at the end of the selection process. It is quite an intuitive approach.

```
private void comboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {            
        // do something fancy with comboBox1.SelectedItem
    }
}
```

otherwise you could also use a timer (which would be unnecessarily complicated and unreliable, also the user would always have to wait and if he switches his decision.... I would not advise this strategy)

EDIT2:

I found a post concerning the suppression of events. So you could basically force the `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` event to "freeze" until you release it. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089072/how-to-prevent-firing-checkedchanged-event-when-checking-a-control-programmatica)

Comment: Thanks for reply.. what I am trying to achieve here is to wait for user's selection while he is trying to select particular value using *down* or *up* key

Comment: @user3762335 ok then you need only to expand the if-condition. See my edit

Comment: Thanks again, but it will not help, when the user uses a key-down  to navigate,    *comboBox1_KeyDown* will get raised for all the selected items one by one and I dt know which Item user interested in. if he is interested in  for example 5th item he will stop pressing key-down after reaching to 5th, I need to know when the user has stopped pressing keyDown then only raise *comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged* event.

Comment: Ok, why dont't you let the user press **enter** after he decided, and then execute the method that you need passing the selected value to the method. The only other possibility that comes to mind is to start a timer after each key press and if the next key press does not come early enough -> take the selected item. Why exactly do you stick to the `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` event? Why don't you write your custom method if you only need it at a certain condition?

Comment: _If he is interested in for example 5th item he will stop pressing key-down after reaching to 5th, I need to know when the user has stopped pressing keyDown._ Then use `Key_Up` event.

Comment: @Berkay good idea, but the `Key_Up` event would result in the same behaviour unless the user is so skilled that he holds the down-button until the selection is reached and then release it. If he misses the desired selection (which is quite probable) he would go up again, and the event will fire again.

Comment: @user3762335 There is actually a way to freeze the `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` event. Check my edit2

Answer (score 0):

Inside the event handler you can do:

```
int index = comboBox1.FindString((String)sender);
```

Then you can check if your index is 8

Answer (score 0):

You can call the event manually,

```
private void comboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e){   
     if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 4)
     {
          ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(comboBox1, new EventArgs());
     }
}

private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
     MessageBox.Show("Test");
}
```

Result;
[image]

### Edit 1;

Use Key_Up event which triggers after pressing to key terminated.

```
 private void comboBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
     ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(comboBox1, new EventArgs());
 }
```

or you can use SelectionChangeCommitted event,

```
private void comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(comboBox1, new EventArgs());
}
```

Hope helps,

Comment: @user3762335 Check updated answer and inform me please.